# How can I parallelise this code?

Tags: parallel-processing

How can I parallelise this code?

```c
for (t = 0; t < _PB_TMAX; t++) {
    for (j = 0; j < _PB_NY; j++)
        ey[0][j] = _fict_[t];
    for (i = 1; i < _PB_NX; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < _PB_NY; j++)
            ey[i][j] = ey[i][j] - 0.5*(hz[i][j]-hz[i-1][j]);
    for (i = 0; i < _PB_NX; i++)
        for (j = 1; j < _PB_NY; j++)
            ex[i][j] = ex[i][j] - 0.5*(hz[i][j]-hz[i][j-1]);
    for (i = 0; i < _PB_NX - 1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < _PB_NY - 1; j++)
            hz[i][j] = hz[i][j] - 0.7*  (ex[i][j+1] - ex[i][j] +
                       ey[i+1][j] - ey[i][j]);
}
```

When I run it parallel, it takes more time than a serial run.

Comment: Wich language? How did you try it?

Comment: #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,50) default(shared) private(i,j,t)